# Trying to pass an id to nodejs with jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to set up friend requests on my app. Since I know who the user is who is logged in (the requesting friend) via req.user, I need to know who's profile the logged-in user is looking at (the receiving friend). Since I'm using pug as a template engine, I couldn't find a way to pass the receiving friend's id as an html id, so I saved it as a title attribute with this:

```
 button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block#addFriendBTN(title = `${user.id}`) Add friend
```

My jquery is this. When I console log `friendId` it does capture the right id and I've checked it's type of as string to make sure.

```
 $('#addFriendBTN').on('click', function() {
        var friendId = $(this).attr('title');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/users/' + friendId,
            data: {
                recevingId: friendId
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#addFriendBTN').hide();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log("err is " + err);
            }
        });
    });
```

In my server-side js in my users file, I have this post route:

```
router.post('/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  var receivingId = req.body;
  console.log("User Id is " + receivingId);
});
```

But the console log (in the browser) is giving me an error so it's not even getting tot he server-side js.

The error I receive is a 500 internal server error and then err is [object object]. Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: `var receivingId = req.body.recevingId;`

Comment: duh. thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: you are sending request to `/users/` but the route you mentioned is `/`. I am afraid if that will hit you end point

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the body object, try this:

```
var receivingId = req.body.recevingId;
```